# Prevent text selection after double click

Tags: javascript, selection-object

I'm handling the `dblclick` event on a span in my web app. A side effect of a double click is that it selects text on the page. How can I prevent this selection from happening?

Comment: Obviously depends on use-case, but likely best to turn your span into a button, **not selecting text on double-click is the default with buttons**, and also good for accessibility when a click performs a function. 

Answer (score 406, accepted):

```
function clearSelection() {
    if(document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if(window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

You can also apply these styles to the span for all non-IE browsers and IE10:

```
span.no_selection {
    user-select: none; /* standard syntax */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to actually prevent selection as opposed to removing the selection after the fact? Also, your second if statement could be inside the else if for better readability.

Comment: The CSS looks great!  Any idea if there's something similar available for IE?

Comment: Sorry about the mess with the braces; I grabbed that code from another site without checking. Fixed. There's no IE equivalent, I'm afraid.

Comment: Best to use -webkit- prefix (this is the preferred prefix for Webkit based browsers) in addition to -moz- (and -khtml- if you have a large Konqueror audience).

Comment: This is now available in IE10 as `-ms-user-select: none;` see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/11/controlling-selection-with-css-user-select.aspx  @PaoloBergantino

Comment: The event-binding approach (at the the time of this writing, the Using Jquery answer below) is the better approach.

Comment: @TimHarper: As far as Javascript solutions using a library, sure. Not really sure why that warrants a downvote.

Comment: Sorry Paolo, I thought this was a jQuery question, but on second glance I was clearly wrong. Looks like I was penalized for my downvote... rightly so. My mistake.

Comment: There is also an -me-user-select: none property for Internet Explorer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/user-select

Comment: i named my style `.unselectable` after the html attribute `unselectable="on"` which does not seem to be effective anymore.

Comment: Warning: using "user-select:none" causes several focus issues if also using divs with "contenteditable=true"

Comment: There is a difference between disabling selection on double click and disabling it completely. The first increases usability. The second decreases.

Comment: @RoboRobok I faced that problem. I have a list where you can collapse sub-items by double-clicking, and I wanted to prevent text selection on double click, but not when the user drags across. My solution ended up being removing the current selection from the double click handler. I also thought about returning false from the mouse down just before a double-click, but that ended up being trickier than I was willing to invest the time.

Comment: @JuanMendes I ended up with `user-select: none` styles (plus all prefixes) on `a:active` selector. It works good, selection by dragging will still work, because dragging makes the active link (if there's any) inactive.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but this would disable all ability to select text? Not just preventing a clickable element from being highlighten as selected when the user clicks a custom click event element twice? I still want the user to be able to select my text via click and drag,

Comment: !!!! THE CSS SOLUTION PROVIDED IS NOT RECOMMENDED.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select Presently user-select is not on the standards track and should be avoided!

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK (the javascript solution). At least, not if called from inside the event handler that handles the double click, which is the only place where it would be of any use.

Comment: This answer is missing where clearSelection() would get called. Here you go add to answer if you want:   $('#myElement').on('mousedown', function() {
   clearSelection();
  })

Comment: Chrome selects text in next text element if you dclick on a preceeding div.. ..which then messes up subsequent mousemove/down behaviour on the div - clearing the selection fixes it ( log any dclick on the div and clear selections if mousemove/down on it later while logged dclick uncorrected )

Comment: @dudewad in fact (at this time) it is in fact on a standards track ([CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#propdef-user-select)).  I realize this has probably changed since you posted your comment, but for completeness, thought it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 156):

To prevent text selection ONLY after a double click:

You could use `MouseEvent#detail` property.
For `mousedown` or `mouseup` events, it is 1 plus the current click count.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (event.detail > 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // of course, you still do not know what you prevent here...
    // You could also check event.ctrlKey/event.shiftKey/event.altKey
    // to not prevent something useful.
  }
}, false);
```

```html
Some dummy text
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail

Comment: This is awesome! Works in Firefox 53.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Everything else here prevents any mouse selection (or worse) instead of answering OP's question "*Prevent text selection after double click*"

Comment: Works in Chrome, too

Comment: Works also on IE 11 Windows 10 =). Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: Use `(event.detail === 2)` to really prevent ONLY double-click (and not triple-click etc.)

Comment: Why? When we have a `dblclick` event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event

Comment: @Catalin, because, it seems, `dblclick` fires after `mouseup` and selection happens after `mousedown`

Comment: This is awesome! Works in Chrome 83.

Comment: Since text is also selected on triple click and quadruple click and so on, I used (event.detail >= 2), which worked as expected.

Answer (score 124):

In plain javascript:

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Or with jQuery:

```
jQuery(element).mousedown(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: Yep, I used this to solve the same problem I was having (+1), except instead of `return false` used `event.preventDefault()` which doesn't kill any other handlers you might have on mousedown.

Comment: This breaks textarea elements on the page  :(

Comment: @johnktejik only if `element` is a textarea, yes.

Comment: Would expect to have this event handler assigned to "dblclick" – but that does not work, which is so weird. With "mousedown", you are of course also prevented from selecting text by dragging.

Answer (score 71):

FWIW, I set `user-select: none` to the **parent element** of those child elements that I don't want somehow selected when double clicking anywhere on the parent element. And it works! Cool thing is `contenteditable="true"`, text selection and etc. still works on the child elements!

So like:

```
<div style="user-select: none">
  <p>haha</p>
  <p>haha</p>
  <p>haha</p>
  <p>haha</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, peppering `style="user-select: note"` everywhere sorted the issue i was trying to solve :)

Comment: Nice css-only solution for cases where you basically never want the text to be selectable. Thanks!

Comment: kyw yaks answers but it could be worse ;)

Answer (score 10):

A simple Javascript function that makes the content inside a page-element unselectable:

```
function makeUnselectable(elem) {
  if (typeof(elem) == 'string')
    elem = document.getElementById(elem);
  if (elem) {
    elem.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
    elem.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
    elem.style.KhtmlUserSelect = "none";
    elem.unselectable = "on";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For those looking for a solution for **Angular 2+**.

**You can use the `mousedown` output of the table cell.**

```
<td *ngFor="..."
    (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)"
    (dblclick) ="onDblClick($event)">
  ...
</td>
```

And prevent if the `detail > 1`.

```
public onMouseDown(mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {
  // prevent text selection for dbl clicks.
  if (mouseEvent.detail > 1) mouseEvent.preventDefault();
}

public onDblClick(mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {
 // todo: do what you really want to do ...
}
```

The `dblclick` output continues to work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to completely prevent selecting text by any method as well as on a double click only, you can use the `user-select: none` css attribute.  I have tested in Chrome 68, but according to https://caniuse.com/#search=user-select it should work in the other current normal user browsers.

Behaviorally, in Chrome 68 it is inherited by child elements, and did not allow selecting an element's contained text even if when text surrounding and including the element was selected.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vue JS, just append `@mousedown.prevent=""` to your element and it is magically going to disappear !

Answer (score 1):

or, on mozilla:

```
document.body.onselectstart = function() { return false; } // Or any html object
```

On IE,

```
document.body.onmousedown = function() { return false; } // valid for any html object as well
```

Comment: This sollution doesn't allow selecting text at all.

Comment: @jmav You would have to apply the function overrides on a more specific element than `document.body`.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent IE 8 CTRL and SHIFT click text selection on individual element

```
var obj = document.createElement("DIV");
obj.onselectstart = function(){
  return false;
}
```

To prevent text selection on document

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.onselectstart = function(){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I came up with a solution that I believe is cleaner since it does not disable every even bound to the object, and only prevent random and unwanted text selections on the page. It is straightforward, and works well for me. 
Here is an example; I want to prevent text-selection when I click several time on the object with the class "arrow-right":

```
$(".arrow-right").hover(function(){$('body').css({userSelect: "none"});}, function(){$('body').css({userSelect: "auto"});});
```

HTH !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it is still perfectly valid in 2021. However, what I'm missing in terms of answers is any mentioning of [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

The OP is asking for the `dblclick` event but from what I see the same problem occurs with the `pointerdown` event. In my code I register a listener as follows:

```js
this.addEventListener("pointerdown", this._pointerDownHandler.bind(this));
```

The listener code looks as follows:

```js
_pointerDownHandler(event) {
  // Stuff that needs to be done whenever a click occurs on the element
}
```

Clicking fast multiple times on my element gets interpreted by the browser as double click. Depending on where your element is located on the page that double click will select text because that is the given behavior.

You *could* disable that default action by invoking [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in the listener which *does* solve the problem, at least in a way.

However, if you register a listener on an element and write the corresponding "handling" code you might as well *swallow* that event which is what `Event.stopPropagation()` ensures. Therefore, the handler would look as follows:

```js
_pointerDownHandler(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Stuff that needs to be done whenever a click occurs on the element
}
```

Because the event has been consumed by my element, elements further up the hierarchy are not aware of that event and won't execute their handling code.

If you let the event bubble up, elements higher in the hierarchy *would* all execute their handling code but are be told to not do so by `Event.preventDefault()` which makes less sense to me than preventing the event from bubbling up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind CSS:

```
<div class="select-none ...">
  This text is not selectable
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is enough :

```
<style>
    #noselect{user-select: none;}
</style>
<div id="noselect"> NON SELECTABLE </div>
```

Answer (score -5):

I had the same problem. I solved it by switching to `<a>` and add `onclick="return false;"` (so that clicking on it won't add a new entry to browser history).