# Double Clicking Table Cell Problem in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I used jquery to attach a double click event handler to a table and display a modal popup when a cell is double clicked.

This works fine in Firefox however in IE8 double clicking the cell causes the text in the cell to be highlighted then displays the "Search Accelerator" button over top of everything.

Is there anyway to prevent IE from highlighting the text in a cell when its double clicked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some approaches to prevent text selection in IE:

- Use of the onselectstart event handler
  http://bytes.com/groups/javascript/92148-ie-preventing-text-selection
- Clearing the selection after the fact
  [Prevent text selection after double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click/880536)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding this on the `TABLE` element:

```
unselectable="on"
```

Though I don't really know when to add it. I'd have to try but I have no IE8 installed.