# disable text highlighting on double click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have this jQuery toggle. It work fine.

```
   <ul>
    <li>Go to the store</li>
    <li>Pick up dinner</li>
    <li>Debug crash</li>
    <li>Take a jog</li>
  </ul>
```

```
        $("li").toggle(
          function () {
            $(this).css({"list-style-type":"disc", "color":"blue"});
          },
          function () {
            $(this).css({"list-style-type":"disc", "color":"red"});
          },
          function () {
            $(this).css({"list-style-type":"", "color":""});
          }
        );
```

The problem is when I do fast clicking, it highlighted the text in it. 
Is there a way to stop the text from being highlighted?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlighted"? Is text selected in the list item if you click during the toggle?

Comment: Just try to double click a text... You will see what I mean... the text will be selected(highlighted)... I don't want the text to be selected...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click

Comment: Note that the question reference by @Aristoteles above has an answer that works correctly (albeit not the accepted one), unlike this question.  Have voted to close on that basis.

Comment: @Jules Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'm writing on iPhone, while away from the desk, but a quick Google turned up this page: [disable text selection with jQuery](http://chris-barr.com/entry/disable_text_selection_with_jquery/).

---

**Edited** in response to the 'dead link' comment (from @Herb Caudill). While the original link is, indeed, dead, it appears to be due to a site restructuring (rather than removal) and the new location for the article can be found here: http://chris-barr.com/index.php/entry/disable_text_selection_with_jquery/

And the code provided in that article is reproduced below:

```
$(function(){
    $.extend($.fn.disableTextSelect = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            if($.browser.mozilla){//Firefox
                $(this).css('MozUserSelect','none');
            }else if($.browser.msie){//IE
                $(this).bind('selectstart',function(){return false;});
            }else{//Opera, etc.
                $(this).mousedown(function(){return false;});
            }
        });
    });
    $('.noSelect').disableTextSelect();//No text selection on elements with a class of 'noSelect'
});
```

#### jQuery snippet written by [Chris Barr, of chris-barr.com](http://chris-barr.com/index.php/), as accessed on Friday, 21<sup>st</sup> of January, 2011.

Comment: This link is broken, can anyone enlighten us as to what the solution was?

Comment: @Herb Caudill, please see the edit (after the `hr`) which links to the new location for the same article, and also includes the relevant jQuery here (with as much citation as I could offer, if @Chris Barr wants to contest its inclusion here I will, of course, remove it from the answer).

Comment: $.browser is deprecated, and binding to an event unsupported by the browser does no evil anyway. So I recommend simply binding “selectstart”, “click” and “mousedown” to a function returning false. This also works in Mozilla, the CSS property MozUserSelect is not needed.

Comment: Nice piece of code. Worked like charm.

Comment: For me, a quick Google turned up *this* page.

Comment: @DavidThomas, may I request you to have a look at a jquery question on a different topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137404/jquery-find-div-class-name-at-a-certain-position-while-scrolling ?

Comment: This prevents any text selection, like click/drag to highlight

Comment: +1 to @madbreaks comment - this does not answer the question asked; it prevents *all* text selection, not just selection on double click.

Comment: This is clearly not an answer to the question.

Comment: @DávidHorváth: it's been over five years since I wrote this, could you explain in what way it's "*clearly not an answer*"?

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry. I am trying to find a solution to this problem **now**, and I have not notice creation time of your answer. IMO, correct answer whould be a description of a method to prevent the browser from build a selection on doubleclick (okay, question is also unclear, for example "highlight" is not "selection"). This is my opinion, sorry again; however, you have even enough likes on this post.

Comment: You don't have to apologise, I was just curious as to your reasoning. Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 37):

I solved this using the non-standard CSS keyword [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select):

```
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: None of the solutions work for me except for you answer, thanks

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer as far as I can see.  Note the standardised version should also be used: `user-select: none;`

Comment: This prevents any selection, not simply double-click selection.

Answer (score 36):

If you use jQuery UI you can disable text selection as simple as that:

```
$("body").disableSelection();
```

Comment: Simple & does the trick.  Thanks!  The browser detection approach has been removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 10):

```
//function to be reused later
function clearSelection() {
  var sel ;
  if(document.selection && document.selection.empty){
    document.selection.empty() ;
  } else if(window.getSelection) {
    sel=window.getSelection();
    if(sel && sel.removeAllRanges)
      sel.removeAllRanges() ;
  }
}

$('p').click(clearSelection);
```

[Source](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/635488-prevent-text-selection-after-double-click)

Comment: Thanks... this did the trick... but ricebowl's suggestion is better...  I'll just give you +1.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
li.noselection::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I tested it on Chrome,  Firefox, EDGE and IE from 7 to 10.

P.S. This only disables the "visual effect", the text still gets selected. I hope that's why this got downvoted, because if your problem is only esthetical this solution works 100%.

Comment: Thanks. This was the perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

To work with jQuery version above 1.9.x

**HTML**

The html markup as shown above:

```
<ul>
    <li>Go to the store</li>
    <li>Pick up dinner</li>
    <li>Debug crash</li>
    <li>Take a jog</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

Use *preventDefault()* instead of *return false* which doesn't kill any other handlers you might have

```
$('li').on('selectstart', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lahmizzar/KMVMt/)

Comment: This prevents *any* text selection, like click/drag to highlight

Comment: This prevents only text selection for _ul > li_ text. Please have a look at the fiddle for testing

Answer (score 0):

```
window.getSelection().empty()
```

works fine in Chrome, albeit with a quick flash of the selection, which is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( 'selector' ).on( 'selectstart', 'selector', function( ) { 
  return false; 
}).css( 'MozUserSelect','none' ).mousedown( function( ) {
  return false;
});
```

replace the selector with your own - this code works fine on all browsers. Using .on() for elements inserted dynamically to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onselectstart = function() { return false; }
document.onmousedown = function() { return false; }
```

Comment: This prevents any text selection, like click/drag to highlight