# Is there any way to disable highlighting in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disable text highlighting on double click in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132172/disable-text-highlighting-on-double-click-in-jquery)

I have a program here that when you click, it fires a turret. but every time you double click it highlights all the pictures. is there any way I can fix that??
Thanks!!

[image: Here is what it looks like:]

Comment: This is native functionality of the browser and is not scriptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable user-selections using css:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```