# JavaScript suppress double click selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm working on a slide gallery at the moment.
My problem is that when i click the navigation divs very fast, the browsers default behavior is fired (selection of content).

My question is: how can I suppress the default double click behavior?

```
navigationDiv.onclick = function () {
  // do something
};
```

A jQuery solution would also be suitable since i'm using it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("yourselector").dblclick(function(){
    return false;
});
```

You can also use **[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**

```
$("yourselector").dblclick(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. The event is firing OK, but neither the *return false* nor the *event.preventDefault()* statements are actually stopping Firefox from double-click-selecting the content.

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI, in Firefox and Safari/Chrome, selection can be disabled through CSS, too:

```
.navigationDiv {
    -moz-user-select: none;             
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
}
```

I think this is more simple when your purpose is only to prevent selections from taking place on a certain element.

Answer (score 3):

You could try disabling the *onselectstart* event of the target element.

```
navigationDiv.onselectstart=function(){return false}
```

Not sure if this is x-browser compatible. (I'll check it)

**Edit**
Turns out that this is a IE-only event. To accomplish the same in Mozilla, you would have to disable the *-moz-user-select* CSS style. In JavaScript that would be:

```
navigationDiv.style.MozUserSelect="none"
```

To be honest, I think you would be better off disabling the double-click event, as described in the other comments here.

Comment: The only problem with this is if a user actually wants to select something using click drag highlighting, you cancel that action too.

Comment: True. I wouldn't use this myself for that very reason, but it *is* an option if all else fails.

Comment: sweet, navigationDiv.style.MozUserSelect="none" in combination with returning false, works now in all browsers! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Putting a `return false;` at the end of the event handler should be able to suppress the default selection behaviour.

Comment: alright, that works in all browsers accept in firefox... any idea why?

Comment: navigationDiv.style.MozUserSelect="none" fixed it in firefox

Answer (score 1):

Calling *event.preventDefault()* in *dblclick* handler will help only if it is called in the element BEING CLICKED, not in the parent's event handler.

In scenarios when there's a container with multiple children, default behaviour of double click will happen in a child and bubbled up to it's parent. In this case there're 2 options:

1. Clear selection in parent's event handler, e.g.: 
   *window.getSelection().empty()*. The issue with this approach is that you'll notice blinking of the selected text and in Opera there'll be a pop-up ('Copy', 'Search').
2. Traverse all children and call *e.PreventDefault()* in their *dblclick*.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the "dblclick" event return false?

```
 $('.someStuff').bind('dblclick', function() { return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the `ondblclick` event:

```
navigationDiv.ondblclick = function () { 
  return false;  // cancel default
};
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Comment: copy: alright, that works in all browsers accept in firefox... any idea why?

Comment: Check my answer why....`return false` doesn't work for Mozilla engines. Rather, stop the event from executing instead of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Quite Simple:

```
navigationDiv.ondblclick = function (event) {
  // do something
  if (!event) event = window.event;
        if (event.preventDefault) 
            event.preventDefault();
        else 
            event.returnValue = false;

};
```

This works on IE and Mozilla browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `e.preventDefault()` nor `return false` ensure in all cases, that double-click's default action (text selection) will not happen. But, having read [this note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53630401/6932612) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321596/6932612) I've composed a working solution for a similar problem of my own:

```
$(...your selector...)
    .on('mousedown',function(e){ if (e.detail>1) return false }) // prevent dblclick default
    .on('dblclick', ...your dblclick handler...);
```