# JS stop highlighting occurring on (double)click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation where if a button is doubleclicked on it highlights the whole button, which is quite annoying, so I've tried to fix it by adding `preventDefault()` to the function to stop highlighting occurring, although I can't seem to stop it happening :( 
Could anyone please tell me why this is ignoring the `event.preventDefault();` and highlighting the button/text anyway?:

HTML:

```
<div class="loading-boundary">
    <div class="redesign-due-date-container">
        <div class="property due_date flyout-owner overdue value-set" style="margin-left:-3px">
            <div class="property-name">
                <span data-icon="calendar" class="calendar glyph toolbar-icon prod"></span>
                <span class="grid_due_date overdue">Yesterday</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".property.due_date").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var e = $(".show-full-duedate");

    if (e.css("display") != "block") {
        $(this).addClass("focused");
        e.css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("focused");
        e.css("display", "none");
    }

    return false;
});
```

I am using the latest version of Chrome to test.
Also, setting the CSS to stop highlighting stops all of the highlighting of the button, even when its not been clicked on, so that is not an option.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by highlighting? Are we talking about a text selection or a CSS style you have set up?

Comment: It selects the text "Yesterday"

Comment: I've setup this http://jsfiddle.net/wEf53/ to demonstrate, if you double click on the word "Yesterday" it will still highlight it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".property.due_date").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var elem = $(".show-full-duedate");

    elem.toggleClass('focused', elem.is(':visible'))
        .toggle(elem.is(':visible'))

    document.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
    event.target.ondragstart = function() { return false; };
    return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wEf53/1/)

The three last lines will prevent the selection.

Comment: Although the `var elem = $(".show-full-duedate");
    elem.toggleClass('focused', e.is(':visible'))
        .toggle(e.is(':visible'))` bit doesn't work

Comment: I changed that a little bit, but had to guess as to what it was you where trying to do, but it seemed like you toggled classes and visibilty based on the elements visibility etc.

Comment: Well my old fashioned if statements work anyways :) this is what works the best based on your answer `event.target.onselectstart = function() { return false; };` ;P

Comment: Yes, that's the line that prevents selection, the next line prevents dragging, and those lines are what I usually add to custom buttons etc. to avoid this exact issue, which can be really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about the element getting highlighted after a double click.

I found a different post asking a similar question. - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117466/javascript-disable-text-selection-via-doubleclick)

It sounds like there isn't a trivial way of disallowing this, but you could "de select" the element after it has been selected.

Hope this helps.