# No highlight when clicking rapidly on an element

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to prevent from text in other elements to not get highlighted when you click rapidly?
I am creating a game in HTML5 canvas which involvs clicking fast and I think it's really unprofessional and annoying if text from other elements start to get highlighted. How could I prevent this?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117466/javascript-disable-text-selection-via-doubleclick answer your question? However, if there is no content where selecting would make the slightest sense use [CSS to completely disable text selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting).

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. What do you mean by "highlighted"? And what "other elements" are you talking about?

Comment: When you click and drag text it gets highlighted... When you double or triple click it does the same thing to text
Edit: It's a good way to do it but I like KG's Way better since it's a lot less complicated. Thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 selection should help you out,

```
::selection {
  color: #fff;
}
```

More [here](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/).

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot less complicated than using functions. How couldn't I think of this? I'll accept your answer when it allows me :)