# Disabling double click selection without disabling drag selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, browser

I'm trying to disable double click selection on certain elements. I have tried

```
$('#rand').on('dblclick', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

and many other variations. I can achieve the effect by preventing default on mousedown but that also disables selection by dragging. How can I disable the double click event without disabling drag and select?

Here's the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/rBRRb/

P.S: I have read many similar questions, but din't find a solution that works for my case.

Comment: I cannot give you better than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click?rq=1 which I am sure you already found. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBRRb/2/). Btw, in your fiddle jQuery is not included even though your code uses it.

Comment: @kapa- Thank you, but it clears selection after it's done which is ok but not a great experience.

Comment: That's why I'm saying I cannot give you better than this ;).

Comment: Why is it that I can prevent this behavior by preventing default on mousedown and not any other way?

Comment: @MattGreen- It doesn't disables text selection, it removes it after selection..

Comment: @questions Because you simply cannot do that. You can disable selection. You can enable selection. But you cannot disable selection by double-clicking ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I found was on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117466/javascript-disable-text-selection-via-doubleclick) post.

```
$("#rand").on('mousedown', function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
});
$("#ran").on('mouseup', function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
});
$('#rand').on('dblclick', function (e) {
    if (window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    else if (document.selection) document.selection.empty();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rBRRb/1/)**

As that is a browser's native behavior you can not "disable" it, but you can modify it like the above that removes the selection after it is made.

Comment: Thank you Matt, but this causes a flash kinda thing which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You should closevote/flag as a duplicate instead of copying an answer from another question.

Comment: @MattGreen- I can disable it by preventing default on mousedown.