# How to disable text selection on a table in a tricky situation?

Tags: jquery, html-table, selection, textselection

I have a basic table, like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On the rows I have a double click function with jQuery:

```
$('tr').live('dblclick',function(){
    dosomething();
    return false;
});
```

I also have a plugin called tablednd that uses mousedown/up function on the rows. 
The double clicking causes text selection on the cells.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `select()` event because it is limited to input elements.

Instead, try `preventDefault()` on the `selectstart` event...

```
$('tr').bind('selectstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hgfre/).

Alternatively, you can use CSS...

```
tr {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on the normal browsers, but no ie8 (if i disable the tablednd plugin, its working on ie8 too)

Comment: @passatgt [See this answer as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click/880518#880518).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$('tr').live('dblclick',function(){
    dosomething();
    return false;
});
```

to

```
$('tr').live('dblclick',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    dosomething();
    return false;
});
```

this should prevent the doubleclick from doing anything the browser will do at default. You should test this code in all browsers though, not sure if it will work everywhere.

Comment: This is not working for me, probably because the tablednd plugin.