# Event listener for dblclick causes event for mousemove to not work and show a circle with a line through it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have event listeners set up for mousemove, mousedown, mouseup and dblclick. The mousedown/up/move all work great by themselves, but when I do a dblclick it fires and then if I try and do a drag then I get a mousedown then a few mousemoves but then a circle with a line through it appears for my cursor and it won't let me drag anymore.  The mouseup seems to get lost but if I click and drag again then I get all of the events as expected. This only happens in Chrome, IE and Firefox both work as expected.

Here's an example that has the same problem that the full site has.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);
        var Debugger = function () {
        };
        Debugger.log = function (message) {
            try {
                console.log(message);
            } catch (exception) {
                return;
            }
        }

        function eventWindowLoaded() {
            canvasLoaded();
        }

        function canvasLoaded() {
            theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
            context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
            context.fillStyle = '#aaaaaa';
            context.fillRect(0, 0, 502, 502);
            var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

            if (theCanvas.attachEvent)
            {
                theCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", eventMouseMove);
                theCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", eventMouseDown);
                theCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup", eventMouseUp);
                theCanvas.addEventListener("dblclick", eventDoubleClick);
            }
            else if (theCanvas.addEventListener)
            {
                theCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", eventMouseMove, false);
                theCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", eventMouseDown, false);
                theCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup", eventMouseUp, false);
                theCanvas.addEventListener("dblclick", eventDoubleClick, false);
            }
        }

        function eventDoubleClick(e) {
            Debugger.log("double click: " + e);
        }

        function eventMouseMove(e) {
            Debugger.log("mouseMove");
        }

        function eventMouseDown(e) {
            Debugger.log("mouse Down");
        }

        function eventMouseUp(e) {
            Debugger.log("mouseUp");
        }

    </script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="leftAll" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
        <img src="images\GTWeb-gray-50x90.png" alt="GTWeb"/>
        <div id="version">
        </div>
        <div id="leftDiv">
        <canvas id="canvasOne" width="502" height="502">Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.</canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

It appears that the double click event is highlighting the image above the canvas, though I can't see the highlight in my full site.  If I take the image out then the problem is fixed.  Is there anyway that I can clear the double click or make it so it doesn't select the image above the canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to clear the selection after the double click using:

```
if (window.getSelection)
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
else if (document.selection)
    document.selection.empty();
```

Comment: Thx in 2021 (Chrome 91)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; alternatively check out the solution at
[Prevent text selection after double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click)
for a CSS solution that works (for me) if you prefer CSS jiggery-pokery to JS jiggery-pokery.  Thanks to all involved!