# How to prevent the double-click select text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, dom-events, textselection

Say I have an `ul` (`li`) list in the page:

```
<ul>
 <li>xxx<li>
 <li>xxx<li>
</ul>
```

The element `li` are clickable and double-clickable, they are attached with these events, and I `return false` in both of them.

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
    //do what I want
    return false;
}).on('dblclick',function(){
    //do what I want
    return false;
});
```

But when the user double-clicks the element, the text inside the `li` will be selected. How can this be prevented?

> **Update:**

Solved now,I use the following code with the css selector by **NiftyDude**:

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
    //do what I want
    return false;
}).....on('dragstart',function(){return false;}).on('selectstart',function(){return false;});
```

Comment: As a side note, you probably want to use [`e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).

Comment: It's not supposed to be a solution, it's just something that you should know and do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click

Comment: `return false;` is the same as calling both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the event handler arg. Perhaps the best thing to do, though, would be to just pass `false` directly:

`/*....*/.on('dragstart selectstart', false);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can disable text selection using css (Note that this will effectively disable all selection methods and not just double clicking)

```
ul li {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T3d7v/1/

Comment: Note that this will disable *all* selection methods, not just double clicking.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks Mr. Marshall :)

Comment: @hguser which version of ie? 6/7?

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop the select from happening but you can clear the selection right after it's made:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.ondblclick = function(evt) {
    if (window.getSelection)
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    else if (document.selection)
        document.selection.empty();
}
</script>
```

To also prevent selecting whole paragraph by  "triple click", here is the required code:

```
var _tripleClickTimer = 0;
document.ondblclick = function(evt) {
    ClearSelection();
    window.clearTimeout(_tripleClickTimer);

    //handle triple click selecting whole paragraph
    document.onclick = function() {
        ClearSelection();
    };

    _tripleClickTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
           document.onclick = null; 
    }, 1000);
};

function ClearSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection)
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    else if (document.selection)
        document.selection.empty();
}
```

[Source/Live test](http://jsfiddle.net/uQNBX/).

This should work on any browser, please report any browser where it's not working.

Comment: Yes, but then I would say you must re-word your question. If you notice, you are unable to select the test due to double (and triple) click... Which is EXACTLY what you wanted...

Comment: Oh,My mistake. I thought it can prevent the dbl-select and select. It works. Thank you.

Comment: would you like something that prevents select as well?