# Change default select behavior for entire document or window

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this I'd like to change the default select behavior for a document.  I do that for the document body with `getElmentsByTagName`.  But the code doesn't actually have the desired effect, which is to prevent the user from clicking to select text in the document.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready ( function () {
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    });
</script>
```

This works elsewhere on my site to prevent select on specific page elements. How do I do this for the entire document?

Comment: You can prevent selection purely using CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I could also do this with CSS with this.

```
<style>
*:not(input) {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;      
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your function. When you select an element using getElementsByTagName, you're actually receiving a collection, even if there is only one element on the page. Thus, use [0] to indicate you want the first body element returned in the collection:

```
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].
        addEventListener('mousedown', 
            function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }, false);
```

This will of course prevent text from being selected, so that solves your problem.

**UPDATE:**

**I just now realized you didn't need to disable clicking on anchor tags, but I'll leave this here for people that want to disable those clicks as well.**

However, to prevent links from being clicked, you must use another approach:

```
// bind click event to parent elements of anchor tags,
 // or it won't work properly
$('a').parent().each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href","#");
    $(this).unbind();
    $(this).click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $(document).on('mousedown', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});​
```

[**Another answer on SO.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click)