# Prevent selection from Shift+Click

Tags: javascript, html, selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css rule to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)
>   [Prevent text selection after double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click)

Even though my events are properly prenting default actions, clicking in text and then Shift-clicking in other text is causing a selection. This is undesirable behaviour in this case, since I'm using Shift-click to multi-select these elements.

Is there something I need to do to specifically disable selection here?

EDIT: Found solution to my own problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click). Sorry for wasting people's time.

Comment: and a Javascript/jQuery solution: [how to disable text selection using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)

Comment: I can't believe this question is marked as answered when none of the answers provide what is originally asked. The question is how to prevent selection on SHIFT+Click, not preventing text from being selected at all. Well, it's the Internet...

Comment: @andreak No, that's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this CSS to the section where you want to prevent text-selection:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Earlier versions of IE require you to add the attribute onselectstart, something like this:

```
<div onselectstart="return false">
```

Comment: Which browser uses `-kthml-`?