# mozilla blue highlight color in clickeable javascript elements

Tags: javascript, highlight, mozilla

I have a problem with Mozilla and the classic blue highlight color. But there's no problem with highlighted text, I mean, I've been searching and I tried the ::-moz-selection css property, and it works fine, but the real deal comes with some clickeable javascript events I have on my page, for example...

#### CSS

```
figure:nth-of-type(1) { 
    -o-transform: translate(60%,-25%) rotate(-10deg) scale(0.60);
    -webkit-transform: translate(60%,-25%) rotate(-10deg) scale(0.60);
    -moz-transform: translate(60%,-25%) rotate(-10deg) scale(0.60);
    transform: translate(60%,-25%) rotate(-10deg) scale(0.60); }

figure.active:nth-of-type(1) {
    z-index:10; 
    box-shadow:0px 0px 50px black;
    -o-transform: translate(-6.5%,-13.5%) rotate(0deg) scale(0.70); 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-6.5%,-13.5%) rotate(0deg) scale(0.70); 
    -moz-transform: translate(-6.5%,-13.5%) rotate(0deg) scale(0.70); 
    transform: translate(-6.5%,-13.5%) rotate(0deg) scale(0.70); }
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    <!--
    function listen() {
        var images=document.getElementsByTagName("figure");
        var i=images.length;
        while(i--){images[i].addEventListener('click', focusImage);}
    }
    function heard() {
        var images=document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        var i=images.length;
        while(i--){images[i].addEventListener('click', unfocusImage);}
    }   
    function focusImage(x){
        var target=x.target;
        var images=document.getElementsByTagName("figure");
        var i=images.length;
        while(i--){images[i].className=""; images[i].addEventListener('click', focusImage)}
        if (target.tagName=="FIGURE"){target.className='active';}
        target.removeEventListener('click', focusImage)
        heard();
    }   
    function unfocusImage(x){
        var target=x.target;
        if (target.className=="active"){target.className='';}                   
        target.addEventListener('click', focusImage);
    }
    //-->

    window.addEventListener('load', listen);                
</script>
```

#### HTML

```
<figure> 
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/art_home/01.jpg"  alt="" />
</figure>
```

So... When I click, the figure/img becomes blue highlightning (it disappears if I click on another place)...

I tried all css selectors I know (::selection, ::-moz-selection, visited, active, etc.), and in Chrome I don't have any problem.

Help please!!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Well... I didn't even knew what was that... I've been playin' with it, but don't really know how works

Comment: @user2744115 paste your HTML/CSS/JS code http://jsfiddle.net/ and then click "save" button. With JSFiddle you can share your problem with us, so we can reproduce it.

Comment: ok! but I'm working in localhost, so the images will not show right? (and sorry for my english, I'm from Spain and it's hard for me). there's a problem with it??

Comment: this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/mYg7F/

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work in all non-ie browsers (and IE 10) as per this SO post:

[Prevent text selection after double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click)

In your CSS:

```
.no_selection {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<figure class="no_selection"> 
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/art_home/01.jpg"  alt="" />
</figure>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks! With only the CSS does not work (I don't know if it has to be double click to work, 'cause my event goes with only one click), but with the function I found in the link that you put goes well!

Comment: this one: function clearSelection() {
    if(document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if(window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    }
}

Comment: By the way, thank you so much for the help. I want to mark as useful your answer but it seems that I have enough reputation...