# Double-click without selecting content

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, double-click

How can I prevent the content of a `<td>` from being selected when the `<td>` is double-clicked?

If I manually single-click anywhere in the page following the double-click, the content (selected by the double-click) is un-selected.

However, if I trigger that single-click programatically, the content actually stays selected...

```
$(".tableCell").dblclick(function(){
    $("body").click();
});
```

This gives the same result:

```
$(".tableCell").dblclick(function(){
    return false;
});
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/eYpY6/1/

Comment: I imagine even if I can get the above to work, a flash of selecting/deselecting might be visible. It would be ideal to prevent the initial selection altogether, but I'm open to all ideas...

Comment: Does putting `return false` in the handler fix it?

Comment: @Barmar, same result...

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Kyle Muir, sure. See my edited question.

Comment: And to be clear, you want to disable text selection in the table?

Comment: @Kyle Muir, I guess ideally, the user would still be able to single-click and drag to select text. But only double-clicking would not cause anything to be selected. However, if you have a solution which disables all selecting, including double-click, I will take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowed from this SO answer: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

You can use this:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

in a CSS rule, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/eYpY6/2/

No JS needed :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. That's pretty slick. I am accepting your answer, but if anyone comes along with a solution which still allows for single-click/drag selecting... they might steal it from you ;)

Comment: PS, how did you get your name in the url on jsfiddle?

Comment: Haha fair enough :) As for JSFiddle, if you create an account every time you're logged in it will attribute those fiddles to your account - that includes updating other peoples fiddles. It's pretty sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from another answer: [Prevent text selection after double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".tableCell").dblclick(function(){
clearSelection();
});
});

function clearSelection() {
if(document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
    document.selection.empty();
} else if(window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
}
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eYpY6/3/

Comment: Oh snap, I didn't realize there was a duplicate question out there...

+1, because I it allows for single-click selecting, but the selection still flashes on double-click.

Answer (score 0):

A little late here, but I thought that I'd share this answer. You can disable text selecting on double-click only using a version of the code I wrote in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fond42518/awe8dLob/5/) for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664376/how-to-disable-text-selection-on-double-click-but-not-otherwise/28665011#28665011), which asked for CSS (but I couldn't find an answer, so gave a Javascript answer in case that OP was okay with that). Basically, the code calls for changing click history on double-clicks and then programmatically re-selecting what was previously selecting. This was achieved using `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`. I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but this is what I have for now.