# How to disable text selection on double click, but not otherwise?

Tags: css, html, selection, double-click

There are tons of questions like this one and every answer I've seen is: use `user-select: none`. That surprises me, because disabling selection completely is in most cases very bad idea.

I want to disable selection in my HTML5 app, because I use plenty `<a>` elements without hrefs and when user clicks them fast enough, they get highlighted. That's bad. But I still want them to be able to select their text normally, by holding mouse button down and dragging.

Comment: can you give a simple  live example ?of code and css involved ? a  :focus{pointer-events:none;} would do)

Comment: It doesn't do anything.

Comment: bad guess then, any code of the situation to share ? :

Comment: What code do you need? Question says it all.

Comment: Is using scripting (ex. Javascript) okay?

Answer (score 0):

I have a basic scripting solution. Check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewgu/awe8dLob/). Basically, what I've done is store and restore `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` values based off of Javascript events. I simplified it a lot since the base version. It should work perfectly for disabling text selection on double-clicks.

There's no real way to do this in CSS that I've thought of so far.

Answer (score 0):

not too sure i understand your meaning.
are you trying something like this ?

**Run the demo in the snippet below or in [codepen DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OPZRgK)**

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background: red;
}
::-webkit-selection {
  background: red;
}

::selection {
  background: red;
}
a:active::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}
a:active::-webkit-selection {
  background: transparent;
}

a:active::selection , a:focus::selection{/* focus + tabindex for ie where no href*/
  background: transparent;
}
a {border:solid;}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque <a>habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas</a>. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit <a tabindex="0">Internet Explorer</a>amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

??

Comment: OP wanted something to prevent the user from selecting text when double-clicking. Not selections in general. Your solution completely prevents the user from selecting _any_ text.

Comment: @fond42518 , please run the code snippet and re-read the css used. text is selected anyhow, i only turn the background selection to transparent on <a> tag  when you double click on a word to avoid see the selection made . this is why the pseudo class active is used , of ourse IE sees it different, so the snippet takes a  tabindexed link for the demo:) when href is missing . you can select and copy/paste the text.

Comment: Here's the thing. Your solution (a) only hides the selection highlighting, not preventing it OP wanted to disable selection, not highlighting (b) the text selection is only hidden when a double-click occurs within the specified element (c) double-clicking near the border of the styled elements sometimes selects all text the same way as if it were highlighted normally. Other than those three points, your solution is completely valid, and yes, I understood what you were trying to do. Also don't think this works on some browsers (especially touch).