# How to fix css color on table click

Tags: html, css

I have some strange behavior with a table click. kind of hard to explain.

Please log into my [test site](http://texasicecarving.com) to see (username:admin, password:adminadmin).

There are two problems:

- When you double click on a place other than the text on the small table a different color of blue will appear briefly.
- If you click on the last row in that table the entire page column turns that same color blue.

```css
.table-striped tbody tr.highlight td { 
    background-color: #428bca;
    color:white;
}
.table-hover tbody tr:not(.highlight):hover td {
    background-color: #428bca;
    color: black
}
.table tbody tr:not(.highlight):hover td,
.table tbody tr:not(.highlight):hover th {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table class=" table table-bordred table-striped table-hover">
    <tr><th>No</th><th>Name</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray" class="pointer" ng-class="{highlight: job.JobNumber===selectedJob.JobNumber}">
        <td ng-dblclick="editJobModal(job)" ng-click="selectJob(job)">{{job.JobNumber}}</td>
        <td ng-dblclick="editJobModal(job)" ng-click="selectJob(job)">{{job.JobName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you're talking about text selection. That lighter blue highlight is highlighting text. You might look here for some suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click

Comment: yes you are correct. took care of it! how do i give you credit