# How prevent double click selection but not regular selection with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse

I want implement `text button`.

so user should click on it . but when user clicks twice there is selection markup all around the sentence. so I want prevent this behavior but because the area and the button text himself is just text i want make user able to select the text with mouse gesture like normal selection .

so, in short. 
How i prevent double click selection but not regular selection 
and to make the solution challenging how it can be done with CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent text selection after double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880512/prevent-text-selection-after-double-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321596/1919821

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  if (event.detail > 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // of course, you still do not know what you prevent here...
    // You could also check event.ctrlKey/event.shiftKey/event.altKey
    // to not prevent something useful.
  }
}, false);

//one line verstion
document.onmousedown = e => ((e.detail > 1)? (e.preventDefault():'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  onselectstart="return false" onmousedown="return false" properies. Something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Button text" onselectstart="return false" onmousedown="return false" />
```